# At what depth below the Sun's surface does the density reach that of water?

Tags: the-sun, stellar-atmospheres, photosphere

I'd like to write a short supplementary answer to [A probe floating in Sun's surface](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12293/12102) but in order to do so I need to know at *roughly* what depth relative to the Sun's surface the mass density reaches 1 g/cm^3.

At the bottom of the photosphere the density seems to be either 1E-06 or 1E-09 g/cm^3 as discussed in the question [What is the density profile within the Sun's photosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32727/7982) but how deep do you have to go below that to reach 1 g/cm^3?

Comment: companion question: [What is the density profile within the Sun's photosphere? Which one of these is wrong?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32727/7982)

Comment: Answered in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201235/density-of-the-sun I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sun's density is 1 gm/cc at approximately 50% of the way down towards the core. if radius of Sun is R then at R/2 the density will be that of water.

[@astrosnapper's comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32729/at-what-depth-below-the-suns-surface-does-the-density-reach-that-of-water/32733#comment60429_32729) links to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/201239/83380) in Physics SE. A reverse image search of that unsourced graphic leads to

- Thesis: [Multi-spacecraft analysisof the solar coronal plasma](https://www.mps.mpg.de/phd/theses/multi-spacecraft-analysis-of-the-solar-coronal-plasma)
- NASA: [The Solar Interior](https://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/interior.shtml)
- [Whatever this is](https://cellcode.us/quotes/density-graph-sun-profile.html) shown below
- the link in that image http://www.sns.ias.edu/~jnb/SNdata/Export/BP2004/bp2004stdmodel.dat **provides some raw data**
- the reference in that image is standard solar model BP2004 J. N. Bahcall and M. H. Pinsonneault, Phys. Rev. Lett. 92 (2004) 121301 [What do we (not) know theoretically about solar neutrino fluxes?](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.121301) (also in [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0402114))

[image: standard solar model BP2004 J. N. Bahcall and M. H. Pinsonneault, Phys. Rev. Lett. 92 (2004) 121301]

Comment: @uhoh Your answer beat mine by 2 minutes.  i should be the one deleting an answer. Not you.

Comment: If you want to add your answer back i'll delete mine.

Comment: Thats fine with me. Thank you.