# Density of a sunspot compared to the surrounding photosphere?

Tags: density, sunspots, photosphere

Is the density of a sunspot different by more than a factor of ten compared to the area surrounding the sunspot?

Comment: No. It just is cooler.

Comment: Hmm... both the question [What is the density profile within the Sun's photosphere? Which one of these is wrong?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32727/7982) and its answer(s) give a density for the Sun's photosphere of about $3 \times 10^{-7} \text{g/cm}^3$, Your link says "10^{-9} g/cm^3" which is really $1 \times 10^{-9} \text{g/cm}^3$ which is written "1E-9" in "computerese" rather than "10E-09" so I think you've transcribed that incorrectly and it's incorrect to begin with as well!

Comment: @planetmaker Is a localized plasma that is cooler than the surrounding plasma the same  density?

Comment: of course the pressure balance applies. Yet in sun spots the magnetic pressure accompanies the gas pressure so that density will not be much different